# How to convert a string to long number with 3 decimals in Android using NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I have 4 number pickers and I concat as string the 4 numbers How I am going to convert this into long I using the following

```
String decimals=units2.concat(units3).concat(units4);
String units = units1;
String finalGrade = units1+decimals;
long Grade = Long.valueOf(finalGrade).longValue();
NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("000");
txtGrades.setText(f.format(Grade));
```

But I get instead of 1.234 a 1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
String resultAsString = String.valueOf(units1) 
    + "." 
    + String.valueOf(units2) + 
    + String.valueOf(units3) + 
    + String.valueOf(units4);
Double result = Double.valueOf(resultAsString);
```

Or you could update this line in your code:

```
String finalGrade = units1+decimals;
```

To this:

```
String finalGrade = units1 + "." + decimals;
```

This can be further optimised with StringBuilder and such, but I wanted to present the general idea :-)

Also, from experience, doing stuff like this using Strings ensures you get frontal 0s right (which is important for stuff like numeric passwords), as using numerical calculations will usually result in the frontal 0s being tossed away.

Comment: without decimal format?

Comment: Ah, damn, I misread the question! :O just a sec, I will update

Comment: Here you go. I updated my solution and gave an example how your can be edited :-)

Comment: Are you trying to parse a String "1.234" in Long ? Good luck ;) You have a decimal value here.

Comment: String finalGrade = units1 + "." + decimals; is not working I ve tried it first

Comment: @AxelH - <facepalm> Thanks for pointing that out, I automatically assumed OP got that right... Updating the answer